# Is there a way to make Popup stay open when the application is minimized?

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

When I minimize the application, Popup gets minimized too. Is there a way to prevent minimizing Popup?

EDIT: here is xaml

```
<Popup Name="popup" StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="True" Placement="Absolute" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Border ... />
</Popup>
```

Comment: Popup.StaysOpen is set to true but it still gets minimized with the application.

Comment: Could you please provide code how you open Popup.

Comment: I open Popup using IsOpen="True" in xaml or Popup.IsOpen = true in code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Popup` is part of your WpfWindow therefore when the Window is minimized the `Popup` is also. Your best bet would be to use a NotifyIcon, there is not one native to Wpf but I have used this one by [Philipp Sumi](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon) with success in the past.